# Error building cordova windows8

Tags: windows, cordova, build, tablet

When i build current project for wp8 , everything works fine. When i build for windows8 i get following error :

> : error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft
>   \VisualStudio\v12.0\JavaScript\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WJProject.Default.props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, an d that the file exists on disk.

I have spend a couple of hours searching for solution on the internet but to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been troubleshooting the same issue, but I am building for Windows 7.  However, when I searched, I found this, which is specific to Windows 8, and may be the key to your answer.

Found at http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=570925:

> On that page under Visual Studio it states: "You will also need to install a version of Microsoft Visual Studio ... that supports Windows Store Javascript app creation.."

and

> its Visual Studio Express for Windows 8. I had installed Visual Studio Express for Desktop which is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that the project had VS 12.0 coded as a variable into the jsproj file while I was using VS 14.0 (VS2015). Changing the "12.0" to "14.0" fixed it for me, once I saved changes, closed and reopened the project

.[image]